# build instructions - not getting tarball etc.. and not clear on use

Tags: cordova, build, meteor

I don't understand very well the build instructions at the link below and have 3 questions

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#building

I'm a noob at meteor-cordova-mobile development.  Web searches & docs not giving any enlightenment.

1. Are the meteor cordova build instructions only for the case where you want to deploy to mobile devices?
2. Looking at a working example application I see a build directory for /.meteor/local/build/programs/**web.cordova** that I don't see created in my application
3. Why am I not getting the output the build instructions say I should get- namely -

> a directory at  which includes a server deployment
>   tarball, and the project source for each targeted mobile platform in
>   the /ios/ and /android/ directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#building) to build prepared apps you add the needed platforms to your project and run `meteor build --server my.server.com ~/build` and then find the apps builds in the `~/build` directory.

Comment: so you are saying this build command is only needed for the case of deploying on devices or using the emulators right?

Comment: and further that everything to build meteor/cordova apps is contained within meteor?

Comment: no, this command is only required for submitting the app store